# Update document array field if the new element not exist

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String},
    email: String,
    password: String,
    tasks: [String]
});
```

I need to find the user document (by usename) and then  to push a new task to the tasks array - if it does not already exist in the array.

I came to this solution:

```
user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { username: username, 'tasks': { $ne: task} },
      { $push: { tasks: task } },{ 'upsert': false});
```

But how can I know to catch the reason the update didn't happened?

Is it because the username doesn't exist or is it because the task already exist?

Answer (score 0):

$push will create duplicates in the task array. you need to use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/index.html) operator:

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        username: 'test'
    },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            tasks: 'task'
        }
    },
    {
        returnNewDocument: true
    })
```

Comment: Ok, but if the update doesn't work, how can you tell if it is because of an incorrect username or if this task already exists in the array?

Comment: for that i think you'd have first retrieve the user document -> do whatever checks you want -> save it back to the db with replaceOne. because mongodb doesn't return that kind of data back to the client when an update is done.